# Specifying bin edges when fitting a normal distribution using histfit

Tags: matlab, histogram, curve-fitting, normal-distribution, binning

I want to fit a histogram to some data using predefined bins. All my data points are between 1 and 10, so I want the bins to start from `xmin=1`, and end at `xmax=10`, with a step of `0.5`.

I use the following commands:

```
x = d1.data(:,4); % x is my data
H = histfit(x,10,'normal'); % fits a histogram using 10 bins
```

However when doing the above, bins are determined automatically per dataset and do not correspond to the edges I want. How can I ensure that the same bin edges are used for all datasets?

Comment: Do you have access to the curve fitting toolbox?

Comment: I am in Edit -> Figure properties -> Axes -> Gaussian curve. Is that you mean? I am using matlab 2019a i fit helps you

Comment: Yes  I almost did it. What to do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to the [Curve Fitting Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/products/curvefitting.html), I would suggest another approach that provides the required flexibility. This involves doing the fit "yourself" instead of relying on `histfit`:

```matlab
% Generate some data:
rng(66221105) % set random seed, for reproducibility
REAL_SIG = 1.95;
REAL_MU = 5.5;
X = randn(200,1)*REAL_SIG + REAL_MU;

% Define the bin edges you want
EDGES = 1:0.5:10;

% Bin the data according to the predefined edges:
Y = histcounts(X, EDGES);

% Fit a normal distribution using the curve fitting tool:
binCenters = conv(EDGES, [0.5, 0.5], 'valid'); % moving average
[xData, yData] = prepareCurveData( binCenters, Y );

ft = fittype( 'gauss1' );
fitresult = fit( xData, yData, ft );
disp(fitresult); % optional

% Plot fit with data (optional)
figure(); 
histogram(X, EDGES); hold on; grid on;
plot(fitresult);
```

Which yields the following plot:

[image]

and the fitted model:

```
 General model Gauss1:
 fitresult(x) =  a1*exp(-((x-b1)/c1)^2)
 Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
   a1 =       19.65  (17.62, 21.68)
   b1 =        5.15  (4.899, 5.401)
   c1 =       2.971  (2.595, 3.348)
```

Comment: OK, I would like to ask you, what should I do in order to take normal distribution curve? histfit command in matlab gives normal distribution curve but I can not specify my clusters as I want. Could you please help me?

Comment: @MRpapas I don't understand your question, the code I provided gives you both the fit object (which can definitely be considered as "the normal distribution curve"), and the parameters of the gaussian - which is everything you need to be able to draw the curve. Please clarify.

Comment: Well, before your mention on the code, I used "histfit" command ( see information below: https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/histfit.html). Using this command I have 10 clusters and a normal distribution fit. The problem was that with the use of histfit, the bins ere not defined as I mentioned above (I mean with minimum, maximum value and step). I tried your code but the curve is different with the first curve I had. Do you know what to do?

Comment: @MR well of course it's different - because the bins are different (i.e. the x,y values are different between the two scenarios, which is unlikely to give the exact same result). If you use the same bins that `histfit` detects automatically with the approach presented in this answer, you should get the same curve. In your question you wanted to be able to specify the bins, which is exactly what I demonstrated. You might want to explain the broader problem if you're looking for a different solution.